# innerhtml ng-click not firing inside controller

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
<div id="selectedFiles"></div>
```

Controller:

```
var selDiv = document.getElementById("selectedFiles");


selDiv.innerHTML +=                         
                    "<span style='margin-right: 5px;'>" +
                    "<button id='deleteButton' ng-
                    click='deleteFile()' " +
                    "style='width: 70px;height: 25px;margin-left: 
                    10px;padding: 1px;'>Delete</button>" +
                    "</span><br/><br/>";

// this was added later but still no luck
$compile($(selDiv).contents())($scope);

function deleteFile() {
        // not getting fired
        console.log("inside delete file1");
    }
```

Comment: Why would you use `innerHTML` while you are using Angular ?

Comment: "ng- click='deleteFile()'" means you should deleteFile() under scope. Where you keep that?

Comment: @Hanif since it is not a angular function in wont call that

Comment: @SergeK. I use it because I am generating data dynamically on file change.

Comment: @MyGod You could put that in your HTML and add/remove it according to a `ng-if` condition. This is the point of using Angular.

Comment: @Aman. `onclick` doesn't work either.

Comment: @Aman, please see closely there are "ng-click". Also "$compile($(selDiv).contents())($scope);"

Comment: @Hanif. deleteFile() is inside same controller when I defined innerhtml.

Comment: Then you try: $scope.deleteFile = function() {console.log("inside delete file1"); }

Comment: This is definitely not the right way to use Angular. Quit it and use jQuery if you want to handle your DOM like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you should do it, IMO :

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.files = [];

  $scope.deleteFile = function(file) {
    var index = $scope.files.indexOf(file);
    
    if (index > -1) {
      $scope.files.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});

angular.module("myApp").directive("filesInput", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var files = [];
        
        for (var i = 0; i < elem[0].files.length; i++) {
          files.push(elem[0].files[i])
        }
        
        ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="file" files-input ng-model="files" multiple />
  <div ng-repeat="file in files">
    <div>{{ file.name }} <a ng-click="deleteFile(file)" href="">Delete</a></div>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Got the directive from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074638/3054411).

Comment: Your code is correct. The only thing missing is the multiple file display functionality. If I click `Choose Files` and choose some file then it appears in the bottom with the option to `Delete`. Then when I again click `Choose Files` and choose some other file then file which was chosen earlier gone. I want previous files preserved as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not getting paid to do it. You'll have code it yourself.

Comment: I did what you mentioned earlier and is mentioned in many online resources as well. The required one I tried is what not happening as mentioned in question.

Comment: If I have to select only single file then what's the use of `ng-repeat`. I can rather use object and render it. I want multiple files chosen to display.

Comment: I don't understand. If you want only one file to be selected, then remove the `multiple` attribute and go on. If you want, you can also remove the `ng-repeat` and bind `files[0]` in place or whatever you want. Otherwise, if you want multiple files to be shown, this is what I did here. And if you want to re-populate the input, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47522812/3054411) and apply it yourself :)

Comment: I don't believe the directive was so useful. I just kept `var files = [];` outside of my directive and it worked. Cheers!