# How do you append an image to input tag of type file from Ajax response(image path)?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, model-view-controller, input

I have HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>
      <img id="user_img" height="100" width="90" style="border:solid" />
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="file" title="search image" id="file" multiple name="file" onchange="show(this)" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am appending image to  tag from Ajax response this way:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "@Url.Action("
  JqueryFillControl ")",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: {
    id: Id
  },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    if (response != null) {

      $("#user_img").attr("src", response.EmpPic);
      $('#file').attr("src", response.EmpPic);
    });
  }
})
```

response.EmpPic has image link that populate in `<img>`.

In my scenario I am populating all data in controls with Ajax and than click save to update data.
But my issue is `<img>` populating image but `<input>` does not have image so it does not update record with same image it will be null.

How can I populate image from source to `<input`> tag?

Comment: Seems like you can't do that, as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Comment: @colin what are you sure i dont thing there is any thing in development that is not possible there might be some solution.

Comment: In this case, it's for security reason, as explained in the answers of the linked question.

Comment: Actually, maybe you can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47522812/3797799

Comment: @colinD its tricky it seems like it will work but dont know how i will give it a try